# Print Multi-Page range from a rounded value

Tags: excel, vba

'I am trying to print out a range from larger sheets based upon the value in a different sheet. a is 'the reference value. b and c are the range variable for my 2 large sheets. The large sheet is has '125 rows and I am hiding all rows, then unhiding the rows I need to print, then printing number of 'sheets based on value b, then unhiding all the rows. When I run the code my workbook the first sheet and then breaks the code. I don't know why this isn't stable.

```
Sub Print_Other()

    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim d As Variant
    Dim e As Variant

    a = Sheets("SAP").Range("J2").Value
    b = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Int(a / 5), 0)
    c = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Int(a / 10), 0)
    d = Sheets("Breakdown").Range("P19").Value / 3
    e = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Int(d), 0) * 25

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Big Sheet")
    .Range("1:125").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    .Range("1:e").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .PrintOut from:=1, to:=b
    .Range("1:125").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With
    
With Worksheets("Smaller Sheet")
    .PrintOut from:=1, to:=b
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This may not address your problem, but what are you expecting `Range("1:e")` to do?  - maybe you meant `Range("1:" & e)` ? Are you using `e` as a row? If so, why are you multiplying/rounding it? And is `EntireRowhidden` supposed to be `EntireRow.Hidden` ?

Comment: I am setting 'e' to be the row number that will adjust based on the value of 'a'. I am rounding it because otherwise i would have a decimal value for a Row number. I did not see the error with EntireRowhidden. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: But you understand that `Range("1:e")` is just going to error, right?

Comment: Also notice that you put those `Range` objects inside a `With` statement, but you did not put a period before the `Range` like this `.Range` so the only thing using the `With` is the line `.PrintOut` - The unqualified `Range` objects are referencing whatever sheet is active when the code runs.

Comment: When it does the line before my Range("1:e") the first page of my workbook hides rows 1:125 instead of the correct sheet doing so before breaking. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I was unaware when I added the with statement that I had forgotten the period before each Range was missing. Now it doesn't hide my first Sheet. I still am not sure how to call Row value 'e' without it breaking.

Comment: Did you try `Range("1:" & e)` as stated in my first comment?

Comment: Because of the earlier issue I had reverted that part back. It did work finally, now i just need to adjust by values. Thank you!